# Как выбрать из строки время по маске (напр., 11:00 или 9:30) в php?

Tags: php

В строке наряду с буквами и др. символами имеется время в формате 12:00, т.е., от 1 до 2-х цифр, двоеточие и от 1 до 2-х цифр.

Помогите составить регулярку, которая будет брать только это время.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/([0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2})/
/([0-2][0-9]:[0-5][0-9])/
/([01]?[0-9])|([2][0-3]):[0-5]?[0-9]/
```

Выбирайте любую =)

Comment: подскажите, а как это использовать через preg_match?

Comment: Вот прям как есть так и использовать preg_match('/([01][0-9])|([2][0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/',$Ваша_переменная,$массив_совпадений);

Comment: что-то не получается, строка " u00e0 11:00h", а приходит 11

Comment: ожидается 11:00

Comment: ну вы это смотрите весь массив =) первая и вторая регулярка вернет целиком, а третья в 2 части.

Comment: я нашел свой косяк ) спасибо